# Own property of UserControl in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, viewmodel

I have a user control with 2 grids on it. Now I want to be able to retrieve the grid that has the focus and expose it to my view model. How can I do this in WPF?
I want to fill a property in my view model with the name of the `Grid` that has focus. It seems not to be easy.

Can anyone help?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should reconsider your design if you are exposing UI elements or specific parts to your viewmodel. Usually your viewmodel should not know of any specific ui element. What exactly do you want to do with the name of the ui element? You could listen to a GotFocus event on your two grids
like

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid1" GotFocus="OnGridGotFocus"/>
<Grid x:Name="Grid2" GotFocus="OnGridGotFocus"/>
```

and add this method to your UserControl, in this method you could retrieve it via

```
private static void OnGridGotFocus(object aSender, RoutedEventArgs aE)
{
   string name = (string)(aSender as DependencyObject).GetValue(NameProperty);
}
```

the name could now be written into a `DependencyProperty` which you bind to your view model. But again, i still think you should not do this.

If you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve, maybe we can help you better.

Comment: Thx for your reply. I have a button in my View which saves the content of the grid to an Excel file. But in order to write the correct file, I need to know what grid has focus. So I need a way to retrieve from my usercontrol (with the 2 grids on it) what grid has focus.

Comment: How do you exactly write a Grid, which is a Layouter in WPF, to an excel file? Maybe you mean something different.

Comment: I know this is an old one but I didn't answer the question how I write the WPF grid to an Excel file. The Grids datasource is an collection and I use the EPPlus dll to write the collection to an Excel file. If you need to create an excel file that's a great tool to do it, I use it all the time.